# API Explorer: people.connections.list only returns "nextSyncToken"

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm attempting to use the Google API Explorer to get a list of my contacts. I've tried several times to use the API Explorer for People.connections.list to no avail.

If anyone has any tips on what I may be doing wrong or further info if my understanding is incorrect, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I'm specifying: 
resourceName: people/me
personFields: names,emailAddresses

When I execute, I get a 200 success with only "nextSyncToken".

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Are you sure you have someone in your contacts list for the account you're using? Can you be more specific about any other request details you're using: OAuth scopes, other parameters, etc?

Comment: Thank you, @John. Turns out I didn't have contacts. Silly on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, John for the helpful comment and for pointing out the obvious.

I thought I had "contacts" but instead, I had "Most Contacted" and "Other Contacts". I had to explicitly add contacts from "Most Contacted" or "Other".

Now everything is working as intended.